# How to store temporary data?

Tags: php, mysql

We have a reporting app that does reports and the user can pick a date range and all reports use the same date range. We currently run the same query for each report and I think this is unfeasible since all reports need the same data and it doesn't make sense to run the same query every time.

Anyone has any recommendations on how to temporary store the data so it can be used by other reports?

Comment: Store it in a temporary table to save the report processing over and over.

Comment: If you have the query cache turned on this will be handled for you.. assuming that all the queries are identical.

Comment: The problem is that a user changes the date range constantly, so I would have to store that data in mysql again if I use temp tables. By temporary tables, do you guys mean the build-in temporary table feature in mysql? Some reports are over 2gb, so it can be ram intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Is it MYSQL or MSSQL? If it is MSSQL, I would recommend using temporary tables and then you can drop the table on another submit.

Comment: Why would you not recommend the same for MySQL?